# Force redirect to /index.php/url in Joomla htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a Joomla site with .htaccess URL rewrite. So in Google my links appear as:
DOMAIN/abc ...
Now probably the rewrite mod on the hosting stopped working and I need to redirect all people from Google to link such as:
DOMAIN/index.php/abc ...

I tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: And "it doesn't work" means what _exactly_ ? What happens? Nothing, you see a blank page? You get an error message? Which? Is the wrong rewriting applied? Does the universe implode when you make a request? Please be _precise_ in your question.

Comment: It means that I was getting an 500 error.

Comment: A http status 500 means not much, it does not carry any real information since it is only intended to clients... You will need to take a look into your http servers error log file, that is where you can read what the actual cause of the error is. You wither created a rewriting loop or the rewriting module is not loaded into the http server.

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude the request start with `index` to avoid looping so , change the rules as follow:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^index\.php  https://example.com/index.php%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache